# Is it possible to make samba (smbd,nmbd,winbindd) stop write log to disk and write it only to syslog(rsyslog)?

Tags: rsyslog, samba4

I have samba instance, and I don't need samba write log to disk, but I want write it to rsyslog. And not full_audit, just general log, how to do it?

Options 
`syslog only`  and `syslog` from http://www.sloop.net/smb.conf.html has no effect. Samba still write full log to /var/log/samba/*.log

Comment: Are you entering 
syslog only = yes? Have a look here: http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch04_08.html

Comment: Yes, in my config `syslog only = yes` `log level = 1` `syslog = 1`.

Comment: I see it also must be configured with configure --with-syslog

Comment: configured `smbd -b | grep WITH_SYSLOG 
 (output ->) WITH_SYSLOG`